# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming. This site did not go through the domain naming and voting, but we still need an elevator pitch. So this is to get you started:*

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) seems relevant, even if the elevator pitch blog post isn't up yet.

Answer (score 10):

Tagline: Electronics Q&A. Keeping the magic smoke in since 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Tagline:  Tripping the rift between hardware and software.

Answer (score 2):

**Elevator Pitch:**

A site for getting your electronics and robotics questions answered by professional and enthusiast developers. We cover theory, practical applications, circuit design and troubleshooting, microcontrollers, prototyping, and more from the hobby to professional level.

Answer (score 2):

Totally focused on keeping robots in that narrow gap between "not working at all" and "enslaving all humanity". ... Ooh, blinky lights!

Answer (score 0):

Elevator pitch: Electronics are a lot more fun when you talk about them with friends. Stop by for the conversation.

Comment: Not bad, but it makes us sound like a forum for chatty questions

Answer (score 0):

Tagline: Electronics Q&A. All Hail the Magic Smoke!